# How to override navigation options in functional component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

To override navigation options using class components, it would be something like

```
export default class SomeClass extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle'),
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ headerTitle: someVariableThatComesFromExternalCall })
    }

    ...
}
```

But how can I do this using functional component??

```
export default function SomeFunctionalCompoenent({ navigation }) {

    // How and Where do I change the header title ?

    useEffect(() => { navigation.setParams({ headerTitle: someVariableThatComesFromExternalCall })})
    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: you could do that at the Navigator level ... not the component level

Comment: I forgot to mention and just changed then question. The header title will come from a external call, it's no fixed header title.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Edit**: Note that this answer was based on the current version at that time. The answer below might be more accurate based on your version:

You still need to define navigationOptions on your functional component. You do it like this:

```
export default function SomeFunctionalComponent({ navigation }) {
    useEffect(() => { 
        navigation.setParams({ 
            headerTitle: someVariableThatComesFromExternalCall 
        }) 
    }, [])
}

SomeFunctionalComponent.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `[]` as second param to `useEffect()`. We only want this to fire on initial load.

Comment: @AtlasRider in addition to this, pass any parameters into the `[]` to run the effect again each time those parameters change.

Answer (score 10):

I've got a suspicion the accepted answer isn't for the currently latest version of react navigation (5), and it definitely doesn't work for this version, so here's a working example for @react-navigation/native v5.7.2 :

```
export default function SomeFunctionalComponent({ navigation }) {
  useLayoutEffect(() => { 
    navigation.setOptions({ 
      headerTitle: 'some other title',
    }) 
  }, [])
}
```

I've used this to access react context - to get the user's name and avatar so I can set a nice title bar for them. I've pasted in the code for this in case it helps anyone:

```
import React, { useContext, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import UserContext from '../context/UserContext';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title : userContext.name,
      headerLeft : () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.openDrawer();
          }}
        >
          <FastImage
            style={styles.userPhoto}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            source={{ uri: userContext.avatar }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, [ userContext ]);

  return (
    // etc
  );
}
```

Comment: Works in 5.7.3 as well favored over the accepted answer if you're using functional components