# How to use navigationOptions without writing class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to use `static navigationOptions ={title='blabla'}` without writing in class. For example like so

```
const Screen = () =>{
  static navigationOptions = {title = 'blabla'};
}
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override navigation options in functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505026/how-to-override-navigation-options-in-functional-component)

Comment: @Vencovsky Your question  little bit the same. Differences between your and my question is I want to give title to my Screen's

Comment: Look at the title, it's the same thing. `How to override navigation option` is the same as `How to use navigationOptions` and `in functional component` is also the same as `without writing class`. Everything you ask is the same but with a few different words. If you want to know how to give a title, you can check [react navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/) and you will find it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should work :

```
Screen.navigationOptions = { options }
```

Or second option

```
Screen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({options});
```